# "pygame.sprite.Sprite.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not Player". How can i slove this problem?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

```py
import pygame
from os import path

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,surf):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.img_dir_player = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "res/img/Player")
        self.player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(self.img_dir_player,"ship.png")).convert_alpha()
        self.player_imgR = pygame.image.load(path.join(self.img_dir_player,"ship_right.png")).convert_alpha()
        self.player_imgL = pygame.image.load(path.join(self.img_dir_player,"ship_left.png")).convert_alpha()

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.player_img,(45,30))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))

        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
```

Comment: What is the question? In which line do you get the error? Please show the complete error trace. Please [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `super().__init__()` instead of `super().__init__(self)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `super().__init__()` instead of `super().__init__(self)`.